# Loading chart. Please wait fusion chart HTML 5 in ajax request

Tags: javascript, php, fusioncharts

This is the code which is getting rendered in my smarty file. Its showing Loading chart. Please wait. How to tackle this issue. I am using FusionCharts version 3.2.2.1 & using

```
$objFusionChart = new FusionCharts( 'Column3D', '898', '300', '0', '1' );
$strGraph = $objFusionChart->renderChart( false, false );

$strGraph has the the html content

 <script type="text/javascript" src="module/FusionCharts.js"></script>
    <div id="graph_data" class="sectionContainer report_graph"><!-- START Code Block for Chart 0 -->
    <div id="0Div">Chart</div>
    <script type="text/javascript" ><!--
    // Instantiate the Chart
    if ( FusionCharts("0") && FusionCharts("0").dispose ) FusionCharts("0").dispose();
    var chart_0 = new FusionCharts( {  "swfUrl" : "/Common/fushion/fushion_charts/Column3D.swf",  "width" : "898",  "height" : "300",  "renderAt" : "0Div",  "dataFormat" : "xml",  "id" : "0",  "wMode" : "transparent",  "dataSource" : "<chart   showValues='0'                                                          showBorder='1'                                                          decimalPrecision='0'                                                            canvasbasedepth='10'                                                            bgcolor='FBFAFA'                                                            yAxisMinValue='0'                                                           yAxisMaxValue='5'                                                           showName='1'                                                            numDivLines='4'                                                             divlinecolor='C4C4C4'                                                           outCnvBaseFont='Arial'                                                          outCnvBaseFontSize='10'                                                             outCnvBaseFontColor='5A5863'                                                            canvasBaseColor='5A5863'                                                            baseFont='Arial'                                                            baseFontSize='10'                                                           baseFontColor='636363'                                                          canvasbgcolor='E4EBF4'                                                          hoverCapBgColor='eeeeee'                                                            borderColor='1D'                                                            borderThickness='1'                                                             xAxisName='Lead Events'                                                             yAxisName='Hits'  ><set  value='105'  /><set  value='827'  /><set  value='788'  /><set  value='441'  /><set  value='1'  /><set  value='38'  /><set  value='140'  /></chart>" } ).render();
    // --></script>
    <!-- END Script Block for Chart 0 --></div>
```

[image]

Comment: I've never used FusionChart. Personnaly, I use HighCharts with HighRoller : http://highroller.io/

Answer (score 0):

Load `FusionCharts.HC.js` and `FusionCharts.HC.Charts.js` after FusionCharts.js